# How to write an array to different columns in a datatable?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, datatable

I need to generate a datatable from an array and need to add the array to different columns in the datatable. The VB.net code would be something like:
DataTable.Rows.Add(ID, (A(I),I = 1 to 100), but I know this does not work. Could someone tell me how this can be done so I do not have to list A from A(1) to A(100), like DataTable.Rows.Add(ID, A(1), A(2), ....., A(100))? Thank you in advance!

Comment: `DataTable.Rows.Add(Your array)`. [Adding Data to a DataTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/adding-data-to-a-datatable).

Comment: Thanks Jimi. That was the first I tried, but it did not work. Only the first column contained "System.String[]", all the other columns were empty.

Comment: You haven't specified how many columns your DataTable has. Have you created the Columns? See the [DataColumnCollection.AddRange()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumncollection.addrange) method. Do you have just one Column? The Create it, the use a loop to add a Row).

Comment: Yes, before this line, I have                 DataTable.Columns.Add("AssessmentTypeID", GetType(Integer))
                For JI = 1 To 100
                    ColName = "Col" & JI.ToString()
                    DataTable.Columns.Add(ColName, GetType(String))
                Next JI
So there are 101 columns in total.

Comment: So, you have 101 Columns and one Row? More Rows? What type is your array? What values does it hold? Do I have to ask each possible question or maybe you should provide the required details to let someone identify the problem and solve it?

Comment: The datatable can be one row or more than one row. The array contains strings. But these questions are irrelevant.

Comment: Those questions are NOT irrelevant. Another question can you edit your question and show some code that will compile to demonstrate what you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to do  something like this.
    Dim table1 As New DataTable("Items")

```
 ' Add columns
 Dim idColumn As New DataColumn("id", GetType(System.Int32))
 table1.Columns.Add(idColumn)
 For i As Integer = 1 To 100
   Dim itemColumn As New DataColumn("item" & i.ToString, GetType(System.Int32))
   table1.Columns.Add(itemColumn)
Next i

 ' Set the primary key column.
 table1.PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {idColumn}

 ' Add RowChanged event handler for the table.
 AddHandler table1.RowChanged, AddressOf Row_Changed

' Add some rows.
 Dim row As DataRow
   row = table1.NewRow()
   row("id") = 1
 For i As Integer = 1 To 100
   row("item" + i.toString) = a(i)
 Next i
 table1.Rows.Add(row)
 ' Accept changes.
 table1.AcceptChanges()
```

Comment: Thanks nbk. Really appreciate your help. I will give a try.

Comment: The correct response is to accept the answer by clicking the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer.

Comment: Just did. Thanks Mary